# Disabling the register button with on button click or on form submit , both ways stop the form from being submitted

Tags: php, javascript, forms, double-click, submission

I have been working on this issue and it's driving me CRAZY!.

so I have a register POST form, when submitted , it redirects to same page , though I have the following:

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //include validation and executing code... (another page)
}
```

now the code works perfectly , everything is nice , but I have one issue.

when a user clicks twice in a row , he gets a message that a user with same e-mail is already registered (where the first click has registered him and inserted the info in database)

Now I tried disabling the button with : `Onclick="this.RegisterBtn.disabled=1;"` in the button tags
and i also tried with : `onSubmit="this.RegisterBtn.disabled=1;"` in the form tags.

both stop the form from being submitted , no idea why. I also tried this:

```
onClick="this.RegisterBtn.disabled=1; this.form1.submit();"
```

Now i came up with an assumption that when a button is disabled the "isset" function will return false, if anyone experienced here can confirm that or help me fix this problem , i will be very grateful , am just abit new to php and all this :) ,

thanks alot in advance

EDIT: the form action is null (redirecting to same page), the code including is above the form.

EDIT: When I disable the button, isset($_POST['submit']) always returns false.

SOLUTION: Ok , i did solve it , in case anyone crosses over to my post facing same problem here's how i solved it:

first , when you disable the button, the isset($_POST['buttonname']) will return false at all times. so i have done the following:

instead of this condition I used : if (!empty($_POST)) ..... include the code

and i used the onsubmit (in form tags) .. this.button1.disabled=1; , and now everything works perfectly :-), and form cannot be submitted twice :D.

Comment: Does it make sense to expend effort to safeguard against what is obviously a user error?  Especially since either a) most users won't do it, or b) an offending user should know they did it.

Comment: well, sometimes requests to servers have abit of a delay, a user might think that he didn't send the request , therefor submit the form again. Also there are some pages where users purchase some items, I want to apply this on that pages aswell , so users don't pay double what they should.

Comment: @wallyk, it does make sense. its not unreasonable for a user to fail to make some silly distinction between desktop and internet. I mean, seriously, you usually single click stuff, but in some cases you must double click. many people rightfully default to double clicking everything because it always works. espescially if the action of clicking isnt responsive - it reminds them of the time they figured out that they needed to double click.

Comment: I'm not sure if you like this idea, but what about hidding the button? <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.style.opacity = 0" /> You can even hide this and display a fake button. (Edit: My bad, opacity is numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="this.disabled = true;" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :-) , but it does not fix the problem :(

Comment: umm , you are not talking about the small c onclick instead of onClick right? ^^

Comment: the thing is , when i disable the button , the code is never included

Comment: That makes sense, the button is disabled when the form is submitted. How about you try adding a hidden input to the form, and check for that?

Answer (score 0):

Forget about messing with the form.  Use these simple checks on the server side:

- If a second request to register the exact same email address occurs, ignore it.
- If a different email address occurs, update it.
- If there wasn't one before, then add it.